# How fix foreach loop

Tags: powershell

My foreach loop add all content logs to single line. How fix it to add content to index?

```
$FilterHashTable = @{logname='Application'; providername='Microsoft-Windows-   SoftwareRestrictionPolicies'; StartTime=$StartTime};
$test = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {param ($FilterHashTable) Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $FilterHashTable} -ArgumentList $FilterHashTable -ComputerName 491-517 | 
Select-Object PSComputerName, TimeCreated, Message 

foreach ($id in $test)
{
$PSComputerName = $test.PSComputerName
$TimeCreated = $test.TimeCreated
$Message = $test.Message

Add-Content $logFile  "$PSComputerName, $TimeCreated, $Message"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'add content to index'?

Comment: Hmmm i have all logs in one line. I must make it like how many logs as many lines.
I do not know how to explain. Not like this cpu1, cpu1 | time, time | message, message but 
cpu1, time, message
cpu1, time, message
cpu2, time, message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look there: http://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html

`$id` is the the next element in your list, refer to `$id` instead of `$test`

Try this

```
foreach ($id in $test)
{

$PSComputerName = $id.PSComputerName
$TimeCreated = $id.TimeCreated
$Message = $id.Message

Add-Content $logFile  "$PSComputerName, $TimeCreated, $Message"
}
```

Comment: this is what I ment. Thanks !

Comment: No problem mate